# How to get PostgreSQL's JSON type data in laravel?

Tags: php, json, postgresql, laravel

I created  table

```
-- Table: public.books

-- DROP TABLE public.books;

CREATE TABLE public.books
(
  id integer,
  data json
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE public.books
  OWNER TO postgres;

-- Index: public.books_author_first_name

-- DROP INDEX public.books_author_first_name;

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX books_author_first_name
  ON public.books
  USING btree
  (((data -> 'author'::text) ->> 'first_name'::text) COLLATE pg_catalog."default");
```

and

```
select * from books;
```

[image]

from the laravel:

```
 $testPJSON=DB::select('SELECT * FROM books WHERE data->>"last_name" = "White"');
```

getting null;
what is the best way to get data in Laravel from Postgres JSON type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query should match the data. There is no element `last_name` in the JSON object.

Try this SQL statement:

```
$testP2=DB::select(
          "SELECT * FROM books WHERE data->'author'->>'last_name' = 'White'"
         );
```